# Cannot access $scope.property, but can see it on console.log($scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am populating $scope with data from a get call:

```
httpGetAsync("myUrlWasHere", getBlogPosts, $scope);
```

And my callback seems to be properly returning data because I get the following output on console when printing `console.log($scope)`:

[image: console screenshot]

However, if I try accessing it with `console.log($scope.blogPosts)`, it returns me undefined:

[image: console screenshot 2]

My callback function is this:

```
function getBlogPosts(param, $scope) {
    $scope.blogPosts = JSON.parse(param);
}
```

And all I want is to be able to pass the array inside `blogPosts.items` to Angular, in order to use `ng-repeat`.

Here is the controller:

```
   websiteApp.controller('BlogController', function BlogController($scope) {
        console.log("blog loaded");
        httpGetAsync("myUrlHere",
                 getBlogPosts,
                 $scope);

    //console.log($scope);
    console.log($scope.blogPosts);

});
```

Please, note that these are both console.log that I used in order to provide you the screenshots.
What am I missing? How may I solve it asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AngularJS `$http` service to do GET requests asynchronously.

```
websiteApp.controller('BlogController', function BlogController($scope, $http) {
    console.log("blog loaded");
    $http.get("myUrlHere").then(function onSuccess(response) {
         $scope.blogPosts = response.data;
         console.log($scope.blogPosts);
    }).catch(function onReject(response) {
         console.log("Error ",response.status);
    });    
});
```

The `$http` service is integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle.

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 2):

`httpGetAsync()` is asynchronous (in the name).

---

Therefore, it seems that your program flow is:

1. Run the `httpGetAsync()` function.
2. `console.log($scope.blogPosts)` (doesn't work because data isn't in and callback hasn't been called)
3. Data loaded from `httpGetAsync()` function.
4. `console.log($scope)` (works because callback has already been called).

---

Make sure to run the code that accesses `$scope.blogPosts` after the callback has been called. For example, run `console.log($scope.blogPosts)` at the end of the callback function.

Comment: I am using `console.log($scope.blogPosts)` in the same place as `console.log$scope)`. As you can verify on the code of my controller.

Comment: @DiegoVolpato Again, because the callback hasn't been called by the time of the `console.log()` statements, `$scope.blogPosts` will be undefined. As for why `$scope` has the `blogPosts` property defined at the same time, I am not sure.

Comment: Mr Ninja, You seem to be right. I changed to a sync approach and it worked. Anyway, I would like to know how to solve this issue with the async approach. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @DiegoVolpato you're httpAsync must return a promisen so you can use `then` function and you can console.log within the callback pass to the `then` call. Check angular documentation about Promise and `$q`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you are passing to $scope is not getting passed to $scope.blogPosts, so how you could fix this is firstly define a scope in the function globally and then pull data into it, if it is in a different server js file then use routes to do this but if in same js file then:

```
$scope.data
httpGetAsync("myUrlWasHere",
                     getBlogPosts,
                     $scope.data);
```

Then what you would do is set the value to it by using $scope.data.blogPosts within the function to whatever you are passing but then again, I am not sure how you are doing this without a server js file and a route.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also show us your httpGetAsync method? Have you tried using promises?

```
websiteApp.controller('BlogController', function BlogController($scope) {
    console.log("blog loaded");
    httpGetAsync("myUrlHere", getBlogPosts, $scope)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log($scope.blogPosts);
    })
});
```

Comment: [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.